# JavaScript - Dynamically add table rows in HTML table

Tags: javascript, html-table

I have the following script by which I want to achieve to dynamically add rows in an HTML table on my website:

```
<script>
var globalIterationVariable = 0;
document.onload = $globalIterationVariable = 1;
$('document').ready(function() {
  $('.add_another').click(function() {
      var globalIterationVariable;
      var newRowVariable = '<tr><td><center><input name="nazovPolozky';
      newRowVariable.append(String($globalIterationVariable));
      newRowVariable.append(' type="text"></center></td> <td><center><input name="pocetPolozky');
      newRowVariable.append(String($globalIterationVariable));
      newRowVariable.append('" type="number" step="1" min="1"></center></td> <td><center><input name="jednotkovaCenaPolozky');
      newRowVariable.append(String($globalIterationVariable));
      newRowVariable.append('" type="number" step="0.01" min="0.01"></center></td></tr>');
      alert(String(newRowVariable));
      $("#tbl").append(String(newRowVariable));
      globalIterationVariable++
   });
});
</script>
```

This script though gives me the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: newRowVariable.append is not a function
```

Can anybody, please, help me to get this script working?

Thank you.

**P.S.:** This script is launched once I press a specific button on my website which has a class='button add_another'

Comment: string append? not sure where you got that from. There is no append for strings just like the error states. Learn about string template literals. It will make it easier to read.

Comment: `concat` and not `append` as `newRowVariable` is a string and not an HTMLelement

Comment: document.onload = $globalIterationVariable = 1; <-- what is that doing? You also redeclare ` var globalIterationVariable;` inside so when you do `globalIterationVariable++` you are doing `undefined++`

Comment: document.onload = $globalIterationVariable = 1; This should initiate a global variable once the page loads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a string

```
 var newRowVariable = '<tr><td><center><input name="nazovPolozky';
```

This is a jQuery object

```
 var newRowVariable = $('<tr><td><center><input name="nazovPolozky');
```

This is how you append a string to a string

```
 var newRowVariable = '<tr><td><center><input name="nazovPolozky';
 newRowVariable += "/></td></tr>";
```

Comment: Thank you! This works! I have another question though, how come globalIterationVariable++ does not always gives me it's value +1?
UPDATE: Nevermind, I fixed it by: $globalIterationVariable++

Comment: To be a global variable, it must be declared outside of a local scope. Such as at the top of the script.

Answer (score 1):

You should define ***newRowVariable*** as a DOM element ->

```js
const newRowVariable = document.createElement('tr')
```

Then append the content (your string) to it ->

```js
newRowVariable.innerHTML = `<td><center><input name="nazovPolozky ${$globalIterationVariable}" type="text"></center></td>
```

Notice I use `` and not '' or "", it's because you can use javascript variables inside a string like that ->

```js
const text = "World"
const superString = `Hello ${text}`
// a console.log(superString) will return 'Hello World'
```

Jquery might be usefull when you are a complete begginner, but you'll figure out soon that it's way simpler to use pure javascript ;)

Comment: Thank you! This seems interesting and worth learning for me :)